# Linq com 2 context diferentes utilizando inner join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, expressões-lambda

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta em 2 bancos de dados diferentes (2 Dbcontext)

Tentei de diversas maneiras, uma delas:
faço uma pré consulta no contexto DbMega para recuperar os funcionarios

```
    var FuncionariosLinq = (from Colaborador in dbMega.Funcionarios
                            select new Funcionario
                            {
                                FuncionarioId = Colaborador.FuncionarioId,
                                Nome = Colaborador.Nome,
                            }).ToArray();
```

e depois faço a consulta no outro contexto com `inner join` com essa pré consulta:

```
    var Linq = (from sal in db.fechamentoSalarios
                join Funcionarios in FuncionariosLinq
               on sal.FuncionarioId equals Funcionarios.FuncionarioId into output
                where sal.Data.Year == DataFiltro.Year && sal.Data.Month == DataFiltro.Month
                select new GerenciarSalariosViewModel
                {
                    Data = sal.Data,
                    FuncionarioNome = output.FirstOrDefault().Nome
                    SalarioId = sal.SalarioId,
                    Valor = sal.Valor
                }
          );
```

**Apresenta o erro:**

> The entity or complex type 'WMB.Models.Funcionario' cannot be
>   constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Se eu mudar ao invés de `Select new Funcionario` deixar `select new {`
em:

```
var FuncionariosLinq = (from Colaborador in dbMega.Funcionarios
                                select new Funcionario
                                {
                                    FuncionarioId = Colaborador.FuncionarioId,
                                    Nome = Colaborador.Nome,
                                }).ToArray();
```

**Apresenta o erro:**

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Resolvi enviando a Id do funcionario e na view chamando uma função que recupera o nome do usuario, porém não foi tão perfomatico e creio que isso deve ser algo normal um inner join em bancos diferentes, só não sei como fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segue exemplo que montei com base no seu cenário e obtive a lista corretamente.

```
List<Funcionarios> Funcionarios = new List<Funcionarios>();
using (var dbMega = new Entities_Exemplo_A())
{
    Funcionarios.AddRange(dbMega.Funcionarios.ToList());
}

using (var db = new Entities_Exemplo_B())
{
    var linq = from Colaborador in Funcionarios
                join Sal in db.fechamentoSalarios on Colaborador.FuncionarioId equals Sal.FuncionarioId
                select new
                {
                    Data = Sal.Data,
                    FuncionarioNome = Colaborador.Nome,
                    SalarioId = Sal.SalarioId,
                    Valor = Sal.Valor
                };
    var t = linq.ToList();
}
```

Inserindo um breakpoit na linha `var t = linq.ToList();`, será confirmado o preenchimento com os registro existentes em ambas as tabelas.